# How to set the favicon when viewing source in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, favicon

I have a page that displays the incorrect favicon when I view its source.

In the following image, you can see in the first tab (which is viewing the page) using the correct favicon - `favicon-tenaya.ico`.

[image: Tabs]

However, when you go to view the page's source via Ctrl + U, it seems to display the default favicon - `favico.ico`, which is in the website's root folder:

[image: Incorrect favicon]

Is there a way to get around this? We don't want the favicon changing when they view the source. How does the view source page in Chrome decide which favicon to use?

Comment: The browser doesn't parse the HTML page when you're viewing its source so I don't think there's anything you can do.

Comment: Overwrite the root ico file with your icon

Answer (score 4):

Viewing the source of a page is browser-dependent. There nothing you can do to force it to display a specific icon. For example, Firefox doesn't display any icon at all for a "View source" tab.

However, you can influence browsers to achieve this. For Chrome and your particular web site, replace the existing `favicon.ico` at the root of your web site with your favicon. This is what Chrome displays and yours is the black and white icon you don't want. Even better: rename `favicon-tenaya.ico` to `favicon.ico` (thus replacing the existing `favicon.ico`) and change the HTML accordingly.

As an aside, you don't need two declarations. Just keep the `shortcut icon` one, although the other one should do just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since Chrome does not parse the html it uses default file "/images/favicon.ico" to show as favicon in view-source. If it doesnt find it it look into different other locations too. for example if you use wordpress it uses http://[domain]/wp-content/themes/[theme]/images/favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

In Website, you can mention the favicon like below

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon-tenaya.ico"/>
```

and its working fine.

Where as in view source of chrome, they automattically find the favicon on below path
https://www.tenayalodge.com/favicon.ico

Favicon to be fetched from added `favicon.ico` after your website.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way:

put your **favicon.ico** file on the root of the website.

That should be accessed like: http://www.[domain].com/favicon.ico

Comment: Name should be favicon.ico as this is the default name